# Looking to create column letting me know when a values in a column are surpassed in same column

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a dataframe below, with Close values.
For each value I know to know how many rows it takes to find a value higher that it.
I want to create a column next_close that is calculating this.

For example 12 is first value, and it takes two days to hit 18.
Next value is 11 and since 18 is higher only one day.

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    'Date': ['2023-07-01', '2023-07-02', '2023-07-03', '2023-07-04', '2023-07-05', '2023-07-06', '2023-07-07', '2023-07-08', '2023-07-09', '2023-07-10'],
    'Open': [13, 12, 19, 12, 18, 15, 10, 16, 14, 11],
    'High': [27, 21, 25, 23, 22, 20, 24, 22, 25, 22],
    'Low': [9, 10, 7, 10, 7, 14, 5, 13, 7, 6],
    'Close': [12, 11, 18, 11, 15, 16, 15, 13, 18, 13]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output is something like this:

```
    Date         Open  High  Low  Close                Next_Close
0  2023-07-01    13    27    9     12                      2
1  2023-07-02    12    21   10     11                      1
2  2023-07-03    19    25    7     18                      0
3  2023-07-04    12    23   10     11                      1
4  2023-07-05    18    22    7     15                      1
5  2023-07-06    15    20   14     16                      3
6  2023-07-07    10    24    5     15                      2
7  2023-07-08    16    22   13     13                      1
8  2023-07-09    14    25    7     18                      0
9  2023-07-10    11    22    6     13                      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy broadcasting can avoid a loop:

```
# Convert to numpy
close = df['Close'].to_numpy()

# Compute the dense matrix
diff = close - close[:, None]

# As you want the next day, reset the lower triangle
diff[np.tril_indices_from(diff)] = 0

# Find the first positive values (the next high day)
# Clip negative values to find next_day=0
days = np.clip(np.argmax(diff > 0, axis=1) - np.arange(arr.shape[0]), 0, None)

# Set the values
df['Next_Close'] = days
```

Output:

```
>>> df
         Date  Open  High  Low  Close  Next_Close
0  2023-07-01    13    27    9     12           2
1  2023-07-02    12    21   10     11           1
2  2023-07-03    19    25    7     18           0
3  2023-07-04    12    23   10     11           1
4  2023-07-05    18    22    7     15           1
5  2023-07-06    15    20   14     16           3
6  2023-07-07    10    24    5     15           2
7  2023-07-08    16    22   13     13           1
8  2023-07-09    14    25    7     18           0
9  2023-07-10    11    22    6     13           0
```

Some intermediate steps:

```
>>> diff = close - close[:, None]
array([[ 0, -1,  6, -1,  3,  4,  3,  1,  6,  1],
       [ 1,  0,  7,  0,  4,  5,  4,  2,  7,  2],
       [-6, -7,  0, -7, -3, -2, -3, -5,  0, -5],
       [ 1,  0,  7,  0,  4,  5,  4,  2,  7,  2],
       [-3, -4,  3, -4,  0,  1,  0, -2,  3, -2],
       [-4, -5,  2, -5, -1,  0, -1, -3,  2, -3],
       [-3, -4,  3, -4,  0,  1,  0, -2,  3, -2],
       [-1, -2,  5, -2,  2,  3,  2,  0,  5,  0],
       [-6, -7,  0, -7, -3, -2, -3, -5,  0, -5],
       [-1, -2,  5, -2,  2,  3,  2,  0,  5,  0]])

>>> diff[np.tril_indices_from(diff)] = 0
array([[ 0, -1,  6, -1,  3,  4,  3,  1,  6,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  7,  0,  4,  5,  4,  2,  7,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -7, -3, -2, -3, -5,  0, -5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  4,  5,  4,  2,  7,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0, -2,  3, -2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1, -3,  2, -3],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -2,  3, -2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  5,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -5],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])

>>> days = np.argmax(diff > 0, axis=1) - np.arange(arr.shape[0])
array([ 2,  1, -2,  1,  1,  3,  2,  1, -8, -9])

>>> days = np.clip(days, 0, None)
array([2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def find_high_close(row):
    r = row.name +1
    while True: 
        try:
            next_row = df.iloc[r]
            if next_row["Close"] > row["Close"]:
                return r-row.name
            r += 1
        except IndexError:
            return 0
        
df["Next_Close"] = df.apply(find_high_close, axis=1)

         Date  Open  High  Low  Close  Next_Close
0  2023-07-01    13    27    9     12           2
1  2023-07-02    12    21   10     11           1
2  2023-07-03    19    25    7     18           0
3  2023-07-04    12    23   10     11           1
4  2023-07-05    18    22    7     15           1
5  2023-07-06    15    20   14     16           3
6  2023-07-07    10    24    5     15           2
7  2023-07-08    16    22   13     13           1
8  2023-07-09    14    25    7     18           0
9  2023-07-10    11    22    6     13           0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `.str.get_dummies()`

```
(df['Close'].astype(str)
.str.get_dummies()
.mul(df.index,axis=0)
.where(lambda x: x.ne(0))
.bfill()
.fillna(0)
.sub(df.index,axis=0)
.where(lambda x: x.cumprod(axis=1).eq(0) & x.gt(0))
.min(axis=1)
.fillna(0))
```

or

```
np.clip(np.argmax((np.triu(a) - a[:,None])>0,axis=1) - np.arange(len(df)),0,None)
```

Output:

```
0    2.0
1    1.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    3.0
6    2.0
7    1.0
8    0.0
9    0.0
```